# Refactor hundreds of java classes in one go

Tags: java, svn, refactoring

I have to refactor almost 250 out of 400 java classes from our project, every single class is under version control (svn).
I need to mark every class with a custom javadoc taglet, but not all of them , because many of them are already marked with this taglet (60% more or less)
I need a secure way to do this, i was thinking of creating a tool to read every single file from svn using svn-kit from the head revision, check if it contains the string:

```
@MyTag
```

If yes, skip class, otherwise write it, i need then to put the java class file into a BufferedOutputStream and write on it but i first wanted to hear if there is another option.
Also, i would like to automate this with a tool running as Ant target for every build, so i cant use Eclipse's find and replace.

Thx

Comment: On the plus side, subversion supports atomic operation. On the minus, I'm not aware of a good way to do this automatically. If your algorithm works 100% of the time, you could turn it into an Ant plug-in.

Comment: Why do you need it on every build?  Surely once you've done it and checked it into the repository, that will be enough, won't it?  Or are you saying you need to do it on multiple branches?

Comment: @JimGarrison nothing yet, i'm still in the planning phase,

Comment: If you are on *nix, you may use the `find` together with `sed`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270151/how-to-use-find-exec-grep-and-sed-with-regular-expression-to-replace-part-of

Comment: Personally, having gone through many re-factors in my time, I think the time it takes you to write said application/plugin you could simply past the required missing annotation into each file.  We are talking 400 classes here, that's really not that many.

Comment: @DavidWallace i'm not the only one working on this, and no, i'm planning to put this only on trunk, the reason why i wanna set this as an ant target is because i have to be sure that the people working on the project "they commit 5 or 6 classes a day" dont forget the taglet, and since you cant trust humans.....

Comment: @CodeChimp refactoring is only a part of the job, this needs to be an ant target for future builds

Comment: So you're not asking about how to do a refactor - you're asking about how to prevent people committing something that doesn't meet a certain criterion.  That's a completely different question, right?

Comment: @DavidWallace no, what i'm asking is a solution for the refactoring, i need to first refactor the existing classes, once this tool is there, i can run it @ build time, what i need first, and what i'm asking advise about, is the refactoring part.

Comment: Since you seem committed to writing a tool, here's how to do it: (1) read the entire file into a `String`; (2) search for the tag; (3) if you don't find it, search for whatever delimiter is important to you (probably the start or end of the first JavaDoc comment) and insert the tag before after it; (4) write the file back to disk. Jakarta Commons IO will help you with the reading and writing (don't forget encoding), and everything else is simple string manipulation. But I agree with *David Wallace*: it's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, download cygwin, point to the workspace's src folder, run a find:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec sed -i -b 's/bug/bugfix/' {} \;
```

thx anyway